# Stability of nonlinear system of PDE's

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, stability-in-odes

Let's assume system
$$
\tag 1 \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial t} = \gamma (\mathbf B \cdot \mathbf E),
$$
$$
\tag 2 [\nabla \times \mathbf E] = -\frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t},
$$
$$
\tag 3 [\nabla \times \mathbf B ] = \sigma \mathbf E + \frac{\alpha}{\pi}\mu \mathbf B,
$$
with initial conditions 
$$
\mathbf B(0) = \mathbf B_{0}, \quad \mu (0) \neq \frac{\alpha}{\pi} k|\mathbf B_{0}|.
$$
System $(1)-(3)$ has exact solution for ansatz $\mathbf B = b(t)(sin(kz), cos(kz), 0)$:
$$
b(t) = \frac{B_{0}\sqrt{\delta +B_{0}^{2}\gamma}e^{t(\delta + B_{0}^{2}\gamma)}}{\sqrt{B_{0}^{2}\gamma e^{2t(\delta + B_{0}^{2}\gamma)} + \delta}}.
$$
So at infinity

$b(t) \to const , \quad \mu (t) \to const, \quad \mathbf E (t) \to 0$.

Let's then assume that there are perturbations $\delta \mu , \quad \delta \mathbf E, \quad \delta \mathbf B $ with trivial initial conditions $\delta \mu (0)=\delta \mathbf E(0) = \delta \mathbf B (0) = 0$. If we perturb $(1)-(3)$ by substitutions $\mu \to \mu_{5} + \delta \mu_{5}$, we will get system which has trivial solution $\delta \mu = \delta \mathbf B = \delta \mathbf E = 0$.

I need to check if this solution is stable. I've searched for some books which contains discussion about methods of verification the stability of trivial solutions of nonlinear system of differential equations in partial derivatives like $(3)$, but I haven't found them. Books which I've found contain cases which don't coincide with my case.

Can you help me with searching? Or, maybe, you know the methods for checking stability of perturbed trivial solution of $(3)$?

**Edit.**

Since $\mathbf B , \mathbf E$ are EM field tensor components, in Coulomb gauge I can write $\mathbf E = -\frac{\partial \mathbf A}{\partial t}, \mathbf B = [\nabla \times \mathbf A]$, $\nabla \cdot \mathbf A = 0$, so perturbed system $(1)-(3)$ may be written in a form
$$
\tag 4 \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial t} = -\gamma \left( \frac{\partial \delta \mathbf A}{\partial t} \cdot \mathbf B + \frac{1}{k}\frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t} \cdot [\nabla \times \delta \mathbf A]\right),
$$ 
$$
\tag 5 \sigma \frac{\partial \delta \mathbf A}{\partial t}=\Delta \mathbf A + \frac{\alpha}{\pi }\left( [\nabla \times \delta \mathbf A] \mu + \delta \mu \mathbf B\right),
$$
$$
\tag 6 \delta \mathbf A (0) = \delta \mu (0) = 0.
$$

Comment: Look at the solutions to the perturbed system when $\delta X_i \not = 0$. Since the equations are linear you can (most likely) solve this system. Typically you will either find equations of the form $\frac{d\delta X}{dt} = C \delta X$ or $\frac{d^2\delta X}{dt^2} = C m^2 \delta X$. Both of these examples have  exponentially increasing solutions if $C>0$ so this indicates an unstable system. If $C<0$ then the solution goes to zero of osscillates as time goes by so it is stable. There are general methods to do this (keywords are: 'dynamical systems', 'Stability theory')

Comment: @Winther : unfortunately, the system is nonlinear (look at term with $\mu \mathbf B$ in eq. $(3)$).

Comment: It is not non-linear when you perturb it (to first order). This is what I meant. Then you throw away every second order term $\delta X \delta Y$ and you are left with a linear system of equations.

Comment: @Winther : why I can do that? Is this hint strict?

Comment: That is the whole point of looking at perturbations. It simplifies the system and tells you how the system behaves if *slightly* displaced from its original state. The solutions you find will, consequently, only be valid when the perturbations are small. However if you find exponentially growing solutions then this *generally* signifies an instabillity.

Comment: @Winther : thank you! I'll check.

Comment: @Winther : I've searched for some books, where there is a discussion about stability of linear system of PDE's with non-constant coefficients, but I didn't find anything. Maybe you know where I should try to find corresponding information?

Comment: I will take a look at it when I get some time later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote up some notes on how one can start doing such an analysis. It is far from complete, but hopefully it can be useful.

We start by perturbing the system of equations to find

$$\frac{d\delta\mu}{dt} = \gamma[B \cdot \delta E + \delta B \cdot E]$$
$$\nabla\times\delta E = -\frac{d\delta B}{dt}$$
$$\nabla\times\delta B = \sigma\delta E + \frac{\alpha}{\pi}[\mu \delta B + \delta\mu B]$$

Taking the divergence of the two equations gives us: $$\nabla\cdot\delta B = 0$$
$$\nabla\cdot\delta E = -\frac{\alpha}{\pi\sigma}[B \cdot\nabla \delta\mu]$$ where we have used that $\mu = \mu(t)$ and $\nabla\cdot B = 0$. Taking the curl gives us

$$\nabla(\nabla\cdot\delta E)-\nabla^2\delta E = -\frac{d}{dt}\nabla\times\delta B$$
$$-\nabla^2\delta B = -\sigma\frac{d\delta B}{dt} + \frac{\alpha}{\pi}[\mu \nabla\times\delta B + \nabla\delta\mu\times B + \delta\mu\nabla\times B]$$

It follows that (the general solution has an additional term $\delta \tilde{E}$ satisfying $\nabla\cdot \delta \tilde{E} =0$ which we for simplicity here just assume is zero)

$$\delta E = -\frac{\alpha}{\pi\sigma}\delta\mu B$$

and

$$\nabla\times\delta B = \frac{\alpha}{\pi}\mu \delta B$$

Taking the curl of the equation above gives us

$$\nabla^2\delta B = -\left(\frac{\alpha}{\pi}\mu\right)^2 \delta B$$

This equation has the solution (for simplicity we only include a single $\cos$ term in the solution)

$$\delta B = A\cos\left(\frac{\alpha\mu}{\pi}n \cdot r\right)$$

for some constant vector $A$, unit vector $n$ with $n\cdot A = 0$ and where $r=(x,y,z)$. This is an oscillating (non-growing) solution and thus the $B$-field is therefore stable againgst perturbations (but the perturbations does not vanish with time). It now remains to solve for $\delta E$ and $\delta \mu$ and see if they are also stable.

Comment: Thank you very much! You've helped well.

Comment: How do you think, possibility of adding of $\delta \tilde {\mathbf E}$ to $\delta \mathbf E$ makes $\delta \mathbf E$ unstable, doesn't it?